# Powershell script to get all Azure AD group members AND group owner to CSV

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

Having some trouble trying to write a powershell script to out all AzureAD groups listing all members of the group with the group owners.

I am new to StackOverflow and new to powershell. Was hoping on some assistance?

```
Connect-AzureAD
$groups=Get-AzureADGroup -All $true
$resultsarray =@()
ForEach ($group in $groups){
    $members = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true 
    ForEach ($member in $members){
       $UserObject = new-object PSObject
       $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "Group Name" -Value $group.DisplayName
       $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "Member Name" -Value $member.DisplayName
       $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "ObjType" -Value $member.ObjectType
       $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "UserType" -Value $member.UserType
       $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "UserPrinicpalName" -Value $member.UserPrincipalName
       $resultsarray += $UserObject
    }
}
$resultsarray | Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8 -Path "D:\Script\test1234-Stack.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

```
$array = @()
$Properties=@{}
$Properties.add("GroupDisplayName","1")
$Properties.add("OwnerObjectId","2")
$Properties.add("OwnerObjectType","3")
$Properties.add("OwnerUserType","4")
$Properties.add("OwnerUserPrincipalName","5")
$groups = Get-AzureADGroup -All $true
Foreach($group in $groups){
     
     $Owners = Get-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true
     $Properties.GroupDisplayName=$group.DisplayName
            
     if($Owners -ne $null){
       # group has owner
        Foreach($Owner in $Owners){
    
                $Properties.OwnerObjectId=$Owner.ObjectId
                $Properties.OwnerObjectType=$Owner.ObjectType
                $Properties.OwnerUserType=$Owner.UserType
                $Properties.OwnerUserPrincipalName=$Owner.UserPrincipalName
                $obj=New-Object PSObject -Property $Properties
                $array +=$obj 
    
    
        }
     }
     else{
                #group has no owner
                $Properties.OwnerObjectId=$null
                $Properties.OwnerObjectType=$null
                $Properties.OwnerUserType=$null
                $Properties.OwnerUserPrincipalName=$null
                $obj=New-Object PSObject -Property $Properties
                $array +=$obj  
 
 
 
     }

}

$array | Format-Table -AutoSize
$array | export-csv -Path D:\Script\GroupExportWithAZADOwner.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

I have found two scripts to list Group Members and another to list all members. Is it possible to combine these?

Answer (score 0):

The number of rows for owner and member are not the same.  So some you can't combine all the columns together.  Here is the best I can do.  I changed syntax so the code is using the same objects.

```
$groups = Get-AzureADGroup -All $true
$resultsarray =@()
ForEach ($group in $groups){
    $members = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true
    $Owners = Get-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true
    $Properties.GroupDisplayName=$group.DisplayName 

    ForEach ($member in $members){
       $UserObject = new-object PSObject

       $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "Group Name" -Value $group.DisplayName
       $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "Member Name" -Value $member.DisplayName
       $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "ObjType" -Value $member.ObjectType
       $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "UserType" -Value $member.UserType
       $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "UserPrinicpalName" -Value $member.UserPrincipalName

       $resultsarray += $UserObject 
    }
    if($Owners -ne $null){
       # group has owner
        Foreach($Owner in $Owners){
                $UserObject = new-object PSObject

                $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "Owner ID" -Value $Owner.ObjectId
                $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "Owner Type" -Value $Owner.ObjectType
                $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "Owner Type" -Value $Owner.UserType
                $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "Owner Principal Name" -Value $Owner.UserPrincipalName

                $resultsarray += $UserObject         
        }
     }
     else{
                $UserObject = new-object PSObject
                #group has no owner
                
                $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "Owner ID" -Value $null
                $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "Owner Type" -Value $null
                $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "Owner Type" -Value $null
                $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "Owner Principal Name" -Value $null
                
                $resultsarray += $UserObject
}
$resultsarray | Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8 -Path "D:\Script\test1234-Stack.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I still seem to get error with this. doesnt compile properly

Comment: What line is failing?

Comment: I've decided to do this a different way and have adapted my script. My idea now is to iterate through the list of members of a group and save just the members of each individual group as its own CSV file. Kind of got it but its not saving over the initial array.

Comment: $resultsarray =@() needs to be moved inside the for loop so a new array gets generated for each group.

Answer (score 0):

```
$groups=Get-AzureADGroup -All $true
$resultsarray =@()
ForEach ($group in $groups){
    $members = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true 
    ForEach ($member in $members){
       $UserObject = new-object PSObject
       $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "Member Name" -Value $member.DisplayName
       $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "UserPrinicpalName" -Value $member.UserPrincipalName
       $resultsarray += $UserObject

       $gName = $group.DisplayName
    $resultsarray |   Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8 -Path D:\Script\AzureAD\$gName.csv -NoTypeInformation  
    }
}
```

Comment: I've decided to do this a different way and have adapted my script. My idea now is to iterate through the list of members of a group and save just the members of each individual group as its own CSV file. Kind of got it but its not saving over the initial array